# Name of a notion in Linear algebra/Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrices. Is there any name for the number $$(\text{sum of all off diagonal entries})/2+(\text{
sum of all diagonal entries})?$$

For example, If $A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12} \\ a_{12} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ then I am interested in the number $a_{12}+a_{11}+a_{22}$.

I need this notion for my research purposes. I am planning to call it as total trace of $A$ if it is not defined already in the literature. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.